# What is the best way to pass around User info in a web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I always roll my own authentication -- I have a control issues.

In a web app using Web Forms, which is a better way to drag along user information through a site:

1. Save User object to Session, grab object from Session on page load/init.
2. Save UserId to Session, instantiate new user obj on page load/init.
3. A better way that I don't know about.

Assume 1 web server is being used.

I prefer #2 b/c it guarantees up-to-date data, but it does make more trips to the db.

Please give advantages/disadvantages.

-iw

Comment: Note: if you force State on your web application by using Session State then your application becomes less scalable.  This may not be a concern of yours but I though I might mention it. If you want to read more about this Google RESTful web applications

Comment: The best way: work on your control issues.

Comment: @John Hartsock - I've heard of RESTful apps in regards to MVC model frameworks, but never for Web Form apps. Maybe I should've clarified I'm talking web forms. If you are talking about Web Forms as well, please explain a bit further. I will edit question to reflect.

Comment: @Bas B - thanks for the valued input, it has clearly lead me down the path to the answer I am seeking...

Comment: You should better rely on [ASP.NET Membership providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) if you need to store the UserID/User-Object to the session to persist it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Door #2 Ian.
```

Rolling your own can definitely have its drawbacks - especially in security (Such as *liability*, which is ALL on you now).  Save your user data in the database.  When the user logs in then check to see if they are authenticated and then just take their user authorization with them in the session which should, in my opinion, be stored on your filesystem (not database) if this is how you are handling security.